# passing an array of structs to a function in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, visual-studio-2010, struct

I have already written a program that in functioning properly.  I need to break it off into functions.  I have 3 arrays of structs.  I would like to make a function that reads the information from the file and echoprints it out.  I just need an example on how I would pass it. I would post my code but I do not want the other students to take it.  Thanks.

Comment: Be more specific with your question. That means you need to write more about your problem, wast parts of your question remained in your head. I do not see the connection between a.) 3 arrays of structs b.) a function that reads info from a file and prints it out.

Comment: You should use the homework tag... Also, imho " I would post my code but I do not want the other students to take it." is not nice when asking for help for a homework... ;)

Answer (score 2):

If you are using C arrays:

```
struct A { int v; }
A data[10];

void func(A *array, size_t n) {
}

func(data, 10);
```

Or if you are using a vector:

```
std::vector<A> vec;

void func(std::vector<A>& array) {
}

func(vec);
```

Comment: the raw pointer version would need a `size_t count` parameter also.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are tagging this as "C++", I assume you are using vectors ( :-) )

```
void f1 ( yourVector& yourVector )
{
  // do something with the vector as read-write (for example fill the vector with somthing).
}


void f2 ( const yourVector& yourVector )
{
  // do something with the vector as read-only.
}

int main()
{
  std::vector <yourStruct> yourVector;
  f1( yourVector );
  f2( yourVector );
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't see how this answer is different from @perreal's answer.